# Python: помещение программы в трей (Linux)

Tags: python, gui, linux

Нужно поместить графическую программу на Python в трей на Linux. Как это сделать? Программа в стадии разработки с использованием PyQt, но приму любые примеры на PyGTK. Не предлагайте PyKDE или python-gnome, у меня XFCE.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Код нагло [утащен со StackOverflow](https://stackoverflow.com/a/895721/116546):

```
import sys
from PyQt4 import QtGui

class SystemTrayIcon(QtGui.QSystemTrayIcon):
    def __init__(self, icon, parent=None):
        QtGui.QSystemTrayIcon.__init__(self, icon, parent)
        menu = QtGui.QMenu(parent)
        exitAction = menu.addAction("Exit")
        self.setContextMenu(menu)

def main():
    app = QtGui.QApplication(sys.argv)
    w = QtGui.QWidget()
    trayIcon = SystemTrayIcon(QtGui.QIcon("Bomb.xpm"), w)
    trayIcon.show()
    sys.exit(app.exec_())

if __name__ == '__main__':
    main()
```